# Why do the two test runners (nosetest/pytest vs. python setup.py test) run a different set of tests?

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest, test-runner

When I run my unit tests using `nosetests` or `pytest`, 83 tests are run and none fail unexpectedly:

```
80 passed, 2 skipped, 1 xfailed, 34 warnings in 280.63 seconds
```

However, when I run my tests using `python setup.py test`, 75 tests are run and one fails unexpectedly:

```
Ran 75 tests in 228.599s

FAILED (errors=1, skipped=2, expected failures=1)
```

Why do the two test runners run a different set of tests?  Not only does `python setup.py test` run less tests, it apparently also runs at least one test that `nosetests` or `pytest` doesn't (at least that's my guess to explain why it encounters an error where the other runners do not).

I'm not sure how to distribute a minimum working/not-working example for this, but [this is the package in question](https://github.com/pytroll/fogpy).

Comment: Because `python setup.py test` uses `unittest` from the stdlib to execute tests if you don't specify a custom runner explicitly. Apparently, some tests in your test suite are ignored by `unittest`, but picked up by `pytest`/`nose`. I can take a look at the test suite's diff once the [Travis job](https://travis-ci.org/hoefling/fogpy/builds/547319148) completes. BTW regarding to version building in your setup script - maybe it's worth to take a look at [`setuptools-scm`](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools-scm/)?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Just a silent downvote, I guess - upvoted.

Comment: Ok, I couldn't get the tests to run on Travis with a terse output, but from the look at the tests suites setup, you didn't include all the test classes in suites (e.g. `Test_NightFogLowStratusAlgorithm` in `test_algorithms.py` is not added to suite, probably some more test classes missing in suites), thus `unittest` and `setup.py test` not executing any of the tests in class. `pytest`/`nose` don't require explicit test inclusion and run everything they encounter, thus executing the tests that `unittest` misses.

Comment: Why a test fails under `unittest` and not under `pytest` can't be answered by the output you provided, because it's not clear what test it is exactly.

Comment: @hoefling The observation that one requires explicit test inclusion and the other doesn't sounds like an answer...

Comment: No, it is the answer to your question _Why do the two test runners run a different set of tests?_. `unittest` will only run classes that is included in a suite ([example from your code](https://github.com/pytroll/fogpy/blob/master/fogpy/test/test_algorithms.py#L742)), while `pytest` will run everything that starts with `test_`. The first set is smaller than the second one.

Comment: My question /is/ *Why do the two test runners run a different set of tests?*... will edit for clarification

Comment: Eh, because they implement test collection differently?

Comment: @hoefling Apparently!  That would answer my question.  I strongly suspect that the test that is failing with one test runner is not being run at all with the other.

Comment: Looks like [adding the missing test classes to the suite](https://github.com/gerritholl/fogpy/tree/add-missing-test-classes-to-suite) did not change what tests are being run...

Comment: Again - based on the information you provided, it's impossible to find out what the difference is. I can't execute the tests myself because the travis job doesn't finish and the log is cluttered with output. Run the tests yourself once via `pytest` and `python setup.py test`, clean the log from unrelated output and add both to the question.